# Sizeof and expressions?

Tags: c++

So I just read a chapter about `sizeof()` in my C++ book. What I read is that you only need the parenthesis after sizeof if the operand is a type, where's you can skip the parenthesis when you have an expression, so what I did was did my own test to see what's going on with this. I used the the following code to see what I will get:

```
int main(){

    cout << sizeof 5 + 5<< endl;
    cout << sizeof 10 - 5<< endl;
    cout << sizeof 5 * 5<< endl;
    cout << sizeof 4.5 + 5.5<< endl;
    cout << sizeof 10.5 - 5.5<< endl;
    cout << sizeof 2.5 * 5<< endl;
    cout << sizeof 10.0 / 5.0<< endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << sizeof 5 << endl;
    cout << sizeof 5.0 + 5.0 << endl;
    cout << sizeof 5.5 << endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

The output I get is this:

```
9
4294967295
20
13.5
2.5
40
1.6
4
13
8
```

How does that work? When I have two integer types, bot 4 bytes, when doing an addition, how it becomes 9 bytes? Is it due to one byte for the `+` operator? But still, if so, then how did the 10-5 came out as 4294?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "individual object". You need the parentheses if the operand is a type. Also note  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: Yes sorry, wrong wording :P

Comment: Could the person that donwnvoted this question at least state why? :)
Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`sizeof 5 + 5` it's parsed as `(sizeof(5)) + 5` and not `sizeof(5+5)` due to operators priorities, so it becomes `4 + 5` and `9`. For more info about this, like chris said, have a look at [this table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

For the substraction it's the same, but as the type of the expression is `size_t` which is unsigned, the substraction is done on unsigned ints which wrap around `2^32` which is `4,294,967,296`. Thererfore, `sizeof 10 - 5` is `4 - 5` which becomes `(4,294,967,296) - 1` in 32 bit unsigned arithmetic, that's the `4,294,967,295` you're getting.

*Going further*

Internally during the [parsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parser#Parser) step of the compilation process, each source code statement is transformed into an expression tree (often called [AST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree)), you can [look here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LR_parser) for exemple if you're curious about these things.

For a more hands-on practical understanding, install the [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) compiler and play with

```
clang -Xclang -ast-dump -fsyntax-only source.cpp
```

Which displays the tree from your code. Really nice, but I recommand short code because the output can be overwhelming otherwise ;)

Answer (score 3):

sizeof is only binding to the first thing that follows it.

An integer literal is four bytes, while a floating point literal is eight bytes.  You then follow each of those two values with an addition, subtraction multiplication or division and get the expected mathematical result.  e.g. sizeof(5) -> 4, 4 + 5 -> 9.

The second value in your example is large because of underflow (4294967295 == 0xFFFFFFFF == 4-5 in unsigned use).

Good luck!